# what is normalization?why it is used in DBMS?

Tags: database, computer-science, normalization, rdbms, database-normalization

I want to know that what is the normalization, what are the types of normal forms are there.
And also that why it is used in datbase?

Comment: That's a broad question with many sources available for explanations. You can start here, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: This is repeated question.

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly, normalization's aim is to avoid data redundancy, storing once each distinct information that can be referenced by many, creating different kinds of data relationships as one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization

If a database design is not perfect, it may contain anomalies, which are like a bad dream for any database administrator. Managing a database with anomalies is next to impossible. The following are the types of anomalies.

1. Update anomalies
2. Deletion anomalies
3. Insert anomalies

Update anomalies:-

```
  If data items are scattered and are not linked to each other properly,
```

then it could lead to strange situations. For example, when we try to update one data item having its copies scattered over several places, a few instances get updated properly while a few others are left with old values. Such instances leave the database in an inconsistent state.

Deletion anomalies :−

We tried to delete a record, but parts of it was left undeleted because of unawareness, the data is also saved somewhere else.

Insert anomalies :−

We tried to insert data in a record that does not exist at all.

Normalization is a method to remove all these anomalies and bring the database to a consistent state.

First Normal Form

First Normal Form is defined in the definition of relations (tables) itself. This rule defines that all the attributes in a relation must have atomic domains. The values in an atomic domain are indivisible units.

Second Normal Form

If we follow second normal form, then every non-prime attribute should be fully functionally dependent on prime key attribute. That is, if X → A holds, then there should not be any proper subset Y of X, for which Y → A also holds true.

Third Normal Form

For a relation to be in Third Normal Form, it must be in Second Normal form and the following must satisfy −

```
* No non-prime attribute is transitively dependent on prime key attribute.

* For any non-trivial functional dependency, X → A, then either −

       X is a superkey or,

       A is prime attribute.
```